# How can I check which PHP file is locking the CPU on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, process, cpu-usage

I've tried with `htop` and `strace`, but I can't recognize which files the instruction came from. The only thing  that `htop` shows me is `php-cgi -c /var/etc/php.ini`.

Comment: Did you try the package sysstat?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to get the PID of the php process from htop and then use

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
```

Comment: Same result
%CPU %MEM CMD
78.9  0.0 /opt/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/etc/php.ini